# Why does this react-native-reanimated code block not run every frame?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

The following `react-native-reanimated` node

```
let node = set(myValue, add(multiply(myValue, .99), 0.5 * 0.01);
```

is included in an `<Animated.Code>` block:

```
<Animated.Code>
    {() => node}
</Animated.Code>
```

From my understanding of how this library works, I would expect this node to be updated in every frame, thus producing some kind of `decay` or `spring` animation, putting the value `myValue` with every step 1% closer to the final value 0,5.

However, this does not work. In my app (where there are many more `reanimated` nodes), it updates only in those frames where at least one other variable is updated through either a running clock or an input variable that has changed.

What's the point of using `<Animated.Code>` if not to ensure that this node gets evaluated at each frame?